# Run Powershell command from different server

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have the following powershell command that reads and gives me the status of my .bat scripts depending on the content of .log files :

```
Get-ChildItem *.log | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Name = $_.Name
    Status =
      ('FAILED', 'SUCCESS')[(Select-String -Quiet 'Finished with NO errors' $_.FullName)]
  }
}
```

This command runs perfectly, when running on the same server as the one where the .log files are stored (ServerA), however when running outside of it - no value is returned.
Is there a way to make it run from another server within the same network?

- Server : ServerA
- Directory : c:\Temp\

Comment: Generally, you can use [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1) to execute remote code. The code you have posted could be passed to the `-ScriptBlock` parameter provided you surround it with `{}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example of implementing @AdminOfThings suggestion, with some comments:

```
$servers = "server1", "server2"
ForEach ($server in $servers){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {  
        Get-ChildItem c:\temp\*.log | ForEach-Object {
          [pscustomobject] @{
            Name = $($env:COMPUTERNAME)
            Status =  ('FAILED', 'SUCCESS')[(Select-String -Quiet 'Finished with NO errors' $_.FullName)]
          }
        }#EndOfForEachLogFile
    }#EndOf Invoke-Command
}#EndOf ForEach
```

Comment: Nice, though the `.Name` property was meant to be the log file name, not the computer name (which doesn't strictly need to be added, because the remoting infrastructure will decorate the output objects with a `.PSComputerName` property). Also note that just `Name = $env:COMPUTERNAME` will do (no need for `$(...)`).

Comment: @FoxDeploy, working like a charm. Do you know how I can get the last run time of the .bat script in this output script?

Comment: Last run time would have to come from the script itself as Windows doesn't check last open or last executed or fields like that.  So you could just make your script update a file or echo out the time to a file and then read that.

Comment: The date of the .log file would be enough for my need. Is there a way to have this in the output?

Comment: 'Date = $_.LastWriteTime' - resolves the problem